# Running total of 2 time series from sqlite database in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have an SQLite table like this:

```
DeviceID  UnixTime     DateTime             TotalMWh  IncrementMWh
12345     1506079789   2017-09-22 11:29:49  1.00      0
12345     1506080692   2017-09-22 11:44:52  1.01      0.01
12345     1506081593   2017-09-22 11:59:53  1.02      0.01
23456     1506082495   2017-09-22 12:14:55  1.00      0
23456     1506083397   2017-09-22 12:29:57  1.02      0.02
12345     1506084299   2017-09-22 12:44:59  1.03      0.01
```

I want to show a running total of MWh on a chart, so need to be able to pull a list like [1.00, 1.01, 1.02, 2.02, 2.04, 2.05] and another list of the datetimes that correspond.

Is it better to do this in SQLite, or pull lists and somehow sum+weave them together in Python?

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest using pandas. You can use pandas.read_sql_query to get the DateTime and TotalMWh columns into a dataframe, then pandas plot to make your chart.

Comment: Where does the value `2.02` come from?

Comment: I want a running total of MWh, there are 2 DeviceIDs reporting into the database, on row 2 the first device '12345' has a total of 1.02, then on row 3 device '23456' logs +1 MWh